# Adding new core into Solr

Tags: solr

I want to add a new core into Solr installed on my local host by passing following URL:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=SNGAlias&instanceDir=D:\SNGAlias\solr\ms2&config=solrconfig.xml&schema=schema.xml&dataDir=data
```

But getting the following Error:

> Error CREATEing SolrCore 'SNGAlias': Could not create a new core in D:\SNGAlias\solr\ms2\as another core is already defined there

Comment: Do you already have a core defined under the same name? You'll have to use RELOAD in that case (this changed from Solr 4.3).

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using?

Comment: No, I have a core named collection1 which I configured by going through apache solr tutorial. Just tell me how to add new directory/collection and indexing all files in the specified collection into solr.

Comment: Adding a new core to Solr can be done by just copying the core into the same directory as where collection1 lives and restarting Solr. It'll automagically discover the core when starting (added in 4.4).

Comment: Thanks..I did the same as you said but while reloading Solr i am getting the following exception <SNGAlias: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load core configuration for core SNGAlias>

Answer (score 11):

The existent file `core.properties` needs to be removed first.

In unix you could do:

```
sudo cp -r <solr-cores-dir>/<existent-core> <solr-cores-dir>/<new-core>
sudo chown -R <system-solr-user> <solr-cores-dir>/<new-core>
sudo rm <solr-cores-dir>/<new-core>/core.properties
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=<new-core>&instanceDir=<new-core>&config=solrconfig.xml&schema=schema.xml&dataDir=data'
```