# Solr 8.10 sample core files and how to add new cores

Tags: solr

I'm using regular Solr 8.10.1 (no Solr Cloud)

I start it like `C:\solr-8.10.1\bin\solr start -p 8983`

My folder structure:

```
- solr-8.10.1
    - server
        - solr
            - configsets
                - sample_techproducts_configs
                    - conf
            - mytest
                - conf
                    - lang
                  data-config.xml
                  managed-schema
                  protwords.txt
                  solrconfig.xml
                  stopwords.txt
                  synonyms.txt
                - data
            - samplecatalog
                - conf
                  data-config.xml
                  schema.xml
                  solrconfig.xml
        solr.xml
```

I also copied files from my solr 4.3.2 instance `samplecatalog` to a new folder in 8.10.1.

But when I got to http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cores
I see no cores.

**solr.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr>
  <int name="maxBooleanClauses">${solr.max.booleanClauses:1024}</int>
  <str name="sharedLib">${solr.sharedLib:}</str>

  <solrcloud>
    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>
    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>
    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateSoTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdateConnTimeout:60000}</int>
    <str name="zkCredentialsProvider">${zkCredentialsProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkCredentialsProvider}</str>
    <str name="zkACLProvider">${zkACLProvider:org.apache.solr.common.cloud.DefaultZkACLProvider}</str>
  </solrcloud>
  
  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory"
    class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:60000}</int>
    <str name="shardsWhitelist">${solr.shardsWhitelist:}</str>
  </shardHandlerFactory>
</solr>
```

I just want to have a sample core folder with a schema.xml handlers and a data-config.xml for my entities, so I can start and expand from that foundation.
I checked the tutorials but I can't find any samples or see where I can define cores via my config files.

I also [checked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052139/adding-new-core-into-solr), but that's for a very old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer : `cd` into solr bin directory and run `solr create -c "mytest"`
(@see [`solr create`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/solr-control-script-reference.html#create-a-core-or-collection) command).

---

Basically you can follow this few steps to define a configuration set and create the corresponding core.

- Define `SOLR_HOME` (where to put Solr core(s) config/data) in solr's `bin/solr.in.sh`, or `bin\solr.in.cmd` on windows. It's recommended you separate it from solr sources & binaries.
- Create/move your configuration set in `SOLR_HOME` directory and ensure solr has ownership.
- Run the [`solr create`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/solr-control-script-reference.html#create-a-core-or-collection) command

Here a bash script based on one I oftenly use that does the job (I noticed you are on a windows machine but the principle remains the same) :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
    
SOLR_SRC="/opt/solr"            # symlink to your solr-<version> directory
SOLR_ROOT="/var/solr"           
SOLR_HOME="${SOLR_ROOT}/data"

CORE="mytest"

# Create core config set in SOLR_HOME
cd ${SOLR_HOME}/
mkdir -p ${CORE}/data
# cp -R ${SOLR_SRC}/server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/ ./${CORE}/ # from default conf
cp -R ${SOLR_SRC}/server/solr/${CORE}/conf/ ./${CORE}/

# Set ownership
chown -R solr:solr ${SOLR_HOME}

# Create core
su - solr -c "${SOLR_SRC}/bin/solr create -c ${CORE}"
```